# Compile fla with flex sdk, is it possible?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, compilation

Is it possible to compile fla file created from flash ide to flex sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex SDK can't compile FLA files :(

Comment: you can actually connect Flex to Flash Builder CS5 and further running the project will trigger Flash Builder to do the real work, anyway there is hudge difference between animation related Flash's and Flex SDK which slowly transforms the Flash platform into something which many peoples dreamed from a very long time :)